# pouchdb-adapter-leveldb showing error in leveldown.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, pouchdb, leveldb

Hi Im trying to use **pouchdb-adapter-leveldb** to create local db file to synch & store a cloud data in offline in electron with Vuejs. After installing pouchdb-adapter-leveldb am importing pouchdb to use 
 **leveldb** adapter

```
import pouchdb from 'pouchdb'
pouchdb.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-leveldb'));
var db = new PouchDB('mydb', {
adapter: 'leveldb'
});
console.log(db.adapter);
```

While running this i get this below error:

```
bindings.js?f3ff:158 Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function

at Function.getRoot (bindings.js?f3ff:158)
at bindings (bindings.js?f3ff:60)
at eval (leveldown.js?42be:4)
at Object../node_modules/level/node_modules/leveldown/leveldown.js 
(app.js:1710)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
at fn (app.js:89)
at eval (level.js?ad23:1)
at Object../node_modules/level/level.js (app.js:1689)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
at fn (app.js:89)
```

Im using this pouchdb cdn link:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.0.0/dist/pouchdb.min.js

can anybody help to get this thing clear?

Comment: Had a similar issue with Electron and PouchDB. Consider installing `pouchdb-browser` package and using it for import - `import pouchdb from 'pouchdb-browser`

Comment: thanks @aBiscuit. i try that pouchdb-browser. Is there any blog to move on further steps about how to create LevelDB adapter with electron?